# Moving extensions in AWS RDS (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Initially we installed all extensions in default "public" schema.
Now we have more and more other schemas - thus we want to add extensions and common functions to the schema `common`.

Unfortunately AWS RDS reports back when trying to move the existing ones like this:

```
ALTER EXTENSION "hstore" set schema common;

DBCException: SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: must be owner of extension hstore
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: PSQLException: ERROR: must be owner of extension hstore
```

I am using the default user that is also member of role `rds_superuser`.

Comment: When logged in, check the ownership of the extension using `SELECT extname, extowner::regrole FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension;` (assuming you are on 9.5 - in any other case, you have to join `pg_authid` to get the role name).  The `rds_superuser` is not really a superuser.

Comment: Does not work with RDS: User has also no permission on pg_authid. but I saw that al extensions belong to the same user with id 10...

Comment: Ok, dug deeper - following phenomenon: Extensions in RDS can be created in every schema and also dropped. But not moved. Which is rather bad if you want to correct design errors...

Comment: That sounds bad, yes.

Comment: having a similar issue, any headway?

Comment: non superuser version of pg_authid is to use the pg_roles view